# Different when write function in onCreateView and method in class extends from Fragment

Tags: android, methods, android-actionbar, fragment, declare

In Main class, I declare a StartActivity type variable.StartActivity fragment1 = new StartActivity();

Here is StartActivity class. I call drawTab() method on onCreateView. And It runs OK.

```
package com.example.android.navigationdrawerexample;

import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.ActionBar.Tab;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class StartActivity extends Fragment {
    public static Context appContext;
    ActionBar actionbar;
    int state = 0;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.main, container, false);
    drawTab();
    return rootView;
}

// call draw Tab method
public void drawTab() {
    // ActionBar
    actionbar = getActivity().getActionBar();
    actionbar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

    ActionBar.Tab PlayerTab = actionbar.newTab().setText("Fragment A");
    ActionBar.Tab StationsTab = actionbar.newTab().setText("Fragment B");

    Fragment PlayerFragment = new AFragment();
    Fragment StationsFragment = new BFragment();

    PlayerTab.setTabListener(new MyTabsListener(PlayerFragment));
    StationsTab.setTabListener(new MyTabsListener(StationsFragment));

    actionbar.addTab(PlayerTab);
    actionbar.addTab(StationsTab);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {

    }
    return false;
}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    outState.putInt("tab", getActivity().getActionBar()
            .getSelectedNavigationIndex());
}

}

class MyTabsListener implements ActionBar.TabListener {
public Fragment fragment;

public MyTabsListener(Fragment fragment) {
    this.fragment = fragment;
}

@Override
public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
}

@Override
public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    ft.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);
}

@Override
public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    ft.remove(fragment);
}

}
```

However, it don't need so. I want when I declare a StartActivity type variable  StartActivity fragment1 = new StartActivity();

it doesn't call drawTab() method. It only called, when I call:
 fragment1.drawTab(). And I tried remove drawTab() method on onCreateView

And in Main class I have:

```
StartActivity fragment1 = new StartActivity();
fragment1.drawTab();
```

However ERROR happens. I dont know reason. What is different? I think error happens when I call: `actionbar = getActivity().getActionBar();` on drawTab() not `onCreateView`

help me solve problem? Thanks you!